# c# Поиск числа между диапазоном символов Regex

Tags: c#, строки

Требуется достать числовое значение из следующей строки формата с помощью ***Regex*** url:

```
string text = "http://pk-test5.inf.ru/client/#!/tenderPlans/100005/positions/100635;"
```

значение 100005
Подскажите, пожалуйста, пробую использовать различные паттеры для поиска в диапазоне между ans/ и /pos

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = @"http://pk-test5.inf.ru/client/#!/tenderPlans/100005/positions/100635";
var splitted = str.Split('/');
Console.WriteLine(splitted[6]);
```

Вывод

```
100005
```

Comment: Дело в том, что данное действие нужно произвести через класс Regex